# Center align image in ImageView - Android

Tags: java, android, imageview

I have a problem with centering an image inside an ImageView.
These are my `RecyclerView` rows
[image]

And this is my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/recyclerViewRowParent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:foreground="?selectableItemBackground"
    android:minHeight="64dip">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?listPreferredItemHeight"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="100">


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivDeliveryState"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|left"
            android:layout_weight="15"
            android:scaleType="center"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_home_blue_grey_500_24dp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="60"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:scrollHorizontally="false"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvSubtitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:scrollHorizontally="false"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

        </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="35"
            android:orientation="horizontal"

            android:weightSum="100">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvNotification"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="25"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:lines="1"
                android:maxLength="3"
                android:textColor="@color/blue_gray_500"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/handle"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_weight="75"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:scaleType="centerInside"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_dehaze_blue_grey_500_24dp" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

I want to center the hamburger icon (with id="@+id/handle") on the right horizontally and vertically inside the ImageView but I had no luck until now. What property  am I misusing or what am I doing wrong? 
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you wanted to center the image on the far right of the layout. If that's the case, I think you just miscalculated the percentages. The LinearLayout that contains @+id/tvNotification and @+id/handle should be of layout_weight="25" and not 35 like it is in your code:

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="25"
            android:orientation="horizontal"

            android:weightSum="100">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvNotification"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="25"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:lines="1"
                android:maxLength="3"
                android:textColor="@color/blue_gray_500"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/handle"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_weight="75"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:scaleType="centerInside"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_dehaze_blue_grey_500_24dp" />

        </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: With all the changes I might have.. I'll change soon and keep you updated

Answer (score 1):

set the parent LinearLayout gravity to center

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="35"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:weightSum="100">
```

Comment: still the same.. I can't understand why

Comment: where is the TextView @id/tvNotification? They are both inside a horizontal linearLayout, probably this textview is pushing the imageview to the side. Set tvNotification's visibility to GONE with you are not using it and test again

-EDIT-
Never mind, That's not the problem

Comment: It's the number next to the icon (4 on the first row)